# LINK : fatal error LNK1221: a subsystem can't be inferred and must be defined

Tags: service, windows-services, c++-cli, visual-c++-2008-express

I have no other errors or warning in my solution, which would be great but this error has totally baffled me. I have three projects, one references none, and the other two both reference it.

One is a windowsservice, ah, that is also the one that doesn't link, I think this means I ought to add the service installer class in the morning, thought the MS example doesn't bother on the ServiceBase page of MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

I'll need to test that example later. But if anyone can help in the mean time, thanks.

The project with no references is a dll. The other is a standard app, which up until about a month ago was all that I'd considered building.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to set the subsystem in your C++ project under Project Properties ->  Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem.  And you probably want to use SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Genius. I like the simple solution.

Comment: Also make sure you are setting this for All Platforms.

Answer (score 0):

This is so easy don't worry about this. Let go to you file name and click on right side go to properties and click on **linker** and select the system 
you will see the top option of subsystem select it to first option that is `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)`

[image: correct image for your desire]